# App stuck and no callback url received for react-native-razorpay

Tags: ios, react-native, razorpay

I have added razorpay to my react native application and the app perfectly on Android. But on ios, if the payment is succeeded or rejected, the then or catch method is never called.

```
let options = {
        description: 'Pay Fee',
        currency: 'INR',
        order_id: '',
        key: 'rzp_live_myid', // Your Live api key
        amount: data?.amount * 100,
        name: 'Campus',
        prefill: {
          email: profileData?.Email ?? '',
          contact: profileData?.ContactNo ?? '',
          name: profileData?.StudentName ?? '',
        },
        theme: {color: colors.green},
      };

      if (Number(data?.amount) > Number(amount)) {
        return Alert.alert(
          'ESIM',
          'Entered amount must be less than balance amount',
        );
      }

      RazorpayCheckout.open(options)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
          //   Alert(`Success: ${response.razorpay_payment_id}`);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log('error in here', error);
        });
```